# When desktop save mode set, emacs reverts to old custom themes

Tags: themes, desktop

I was playing around a bit with custom themes.  I found that using them would mess with my other settings and decided I wanted to revert to the standard emacs theme.  I disabled the themes in question and removed calls to enable them in my .emacs file.  But they kept loading.

I found that if I disabled desktop-save-mode (`(desktop-save-mode 0)` in .emacs) that I could finally load with the standard theme.

However, I would like to re-enable desktop-save-mode.  But every time I try to it re-enables the old custom themes and screws up my other settings in my .emacs file.

I'd like to enable desktop-save-mode and not have any custom themes get re-applied when I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across this behavior as well. For me it was always enough to delete the emacs.desktop file, which contains the saved state including enabled modes etc.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you.